# How to set store id to cms block output

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

I am using below code to display static block content but it display only first store block every time.I am load this cms block on admin side.
I have two block with same identifier but assign it to diffrent store so i would like to display it store wise.

Here is code i m using but it didn't help.

```
Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('pdf_page_of')->setStoreId($storeId)->toHtml()
```

Comment: First echo your $storeId and check it gives correct store id.

Comment: yes getting right store id

Comment: may be due to same block name. create block like this pdf_page_of_1 , pdf_page_of_2 and then used your code or $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('pdf_page_of_'.$storeId)->toHtml();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
/* set required store */
    Mage::app()->setCurrentStore($storeId);
            $addresBlock =  Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('pdfaddress')->toHtml();
    Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
/* reset admin store after wind up our purpose.*/
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try the code below:

```
Mage::getModel('cms/block')
    ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
    ->load('pdf_page_of')
;
```

Comment: this way it will load but if there is directive in cms it will not load that

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below with different $storeId

```
$block = Mage::getModel('cms/block')->setStoreId($storeId)->load('newest_product');
echo $block->getTitle();
echo $block->getContent();
```

Comment: not that way @abhinav `Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('pdf_page_of')->setStoreId($storeId)->toHtml()` i wan to load block this way

Answer (score 0):

In this case

```
$blockId = 'block_id';
$storeId = 5;
$block = Mage::getModel('cms/block')->setStoreId($storeId)->load($blockId);
```

Keep in mind that if you have already a block with $blockId in the store id 0, $block will be loaded for store 0, no matter what value you have in $storeId. This happens because store id 0 exists for all other store views.

I'm assuming that

```
Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID
```

returns 0.